# Win7 login without domain to local repository

Tags: windows-7, networking, domain, localhost

In my project I have an alfresco repository running on localhost:8080 and now I want to map the WebDav (`\\localhost@8080\alfresco\webdav`) as a network drive. The problem is my computer is in the company's domain so every time I try to map the network drive it automatically assumes I want to login with username `DOMAIN/admin` with password admin. Choosing the option "Use another account" also still adds the company's domain which is not working because then it will not find it. Using FireFox I can login to `http:\\localhost:8080\alfresco\webdav\` with the credentials admin admin.

How can I map the network drive to localhost WITHOUT the domain?

I also tried

```
net use * \\localhost@8080\alfresco\webdav\ admin admin
```

and all its varieties with the same problem.

Comment: I'm slightly lost: What's the point of mapping a networked drive to the local computer?

Comment: I have to reproduce a problem which only occures if a document was uploaded to the Alfresco repository using WebDAV.

Comment: Ok. Let's stop right there. Please have look at [this post on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), and re-write your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry Iszi I dont get it. I asked straight for a solution and I dont aski for another problem. But again: how can I get ride of the domain user credentials?

Comment: Try `YOURCOMPUTERNAME\YourUsername` as username.

Comment: @gronostaj I also tried this but won't work either